# Add a cloumn of a Dataframe to another dataframe when there is a specific match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe called `df1` that is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

id_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(zip(id_1, data_1), columns =['id', 'data'])
```

[image]

And now another Dataframe called `df2`:

```
id_2 = [1,3,5,7]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(id_2, columns = ['id'])
```

[image]

What I want to know is how can I add the values of `data` from `df1` into `df2` whenever there is a match in `id`.

So basically the desired result would be:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way using `map()`,

```
df_2['data'] = df_2['id'].map(df_1.set_index('id')['data'])
```

here, mapping each `id` of df_2 based on `df_1.set_index('id')['data']` series and setting the value using `df_2['data']`

Using **merge**,

```
 pd.merge(df_2,df_1, how='inner')
```

here, doing simple **inner** join both of `df_1` and `df_2`

Answer (score 3):

Use `map` with `dictionary`:

```
dd = {k:v for k, v in zip(df_1['id'], df_1['data'])}
df_2['data'] = df_2['id'].map(dd)
df_2
```

Output:

```
   id  data
0   1   0.1
1   3   0.3
2   5   0.5
3   7   0.7
```

Timings:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) or [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join) the dataframes:

```
df_2.merge(df_1, on='id')
```

Or

```
df_2.join(df_1.set_index('id') , on='id', how='inner')
```

**Example**:

```
>>> df_1 = pd.DataFrame(zip(id_1, data_1), columns =['id', 'data'])
   id  data
0   1   0.0
1   2   0.1
2   3   0.2
3   4   0.3
4   5   0.4
5   6   0.5
6   7   0.6

>>> df_2 = pd.DataFrame(id_2, columns = ['id'])
   id
0   1
1   3
2   5
3   7

>>> df_2.merge(df_1 , on='id', how='inner') #merging the dataframes
   id  data
0   1   0.0
1   3   0.2
2   5   0.4
3   7   0.6

>>> df_2.join(df_1.set_index('id') , on='id', how='inner')
   id  data
0   1   0.0
1   3   0.2
2   5   0.4
3   7   0.6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dataframes method `merge` to join your data:

```
df_2 = df_2.merge(df_1, how='left', on='id')
```